# Class Level Property for Django model in Python

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model storing some infrequently changed but often used data.  I'm looking for a pattern so that I can refer to them as kind of static class variables, eg, like `SomeModel.Bar` or `SomeModel.Baz`.

At the moment I'm using a staticmethod like so:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @staticmethod
    def Baz():
        #retrieve from cache or lookup Baz item
        return baz
```

Meaning I refer to the items as SomeModel.Baz() but this just doesn't quite feel right.  I just get the impression that I'm doing something wrong.  I don't want to make it a property, as I don't want an instance to refer to the item.

Can anyone point me at a pattern or example to show me is I can implement a class level property in this way?  Or tell me why I should be doing something totally different?  Thanks :).

Answer (score 2):

If you want some logic for model which doesn't belong to particular row, write [custom model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/managers/).